# Do I need a custom ViewMode (MVVM)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to ASP.Net MVC

I want to Display a Different View to Select a School and a Challan, Then to insert ID of Selected Challan and IDs of all Students ( of the Selected School) to be inserted in the Joinning table ie. ChallanAndStudents Table

I have following Entities

```
tbl.FeeChallan, 

tbl.Students (Students belong to different schools),

tbl.ChallanAndStudents (the joining Table of tbl.FeeChallan and tbl.Students )

tbl.Schools
```

The Joining Table has a `StudentID` and `FeeChallanID`

as Business logic says : `FeeChallans` Can be from a single Student or from a whole school.

In Case of Whole School selection, I would allow the User to select School from DropDownList and The ChallanNumber From the 2nd DropDownList.

then On Submit, I have to Insert `ChallanFormID` and `StudentID` (All Students of the selected School into the Joining Table)

ViewMode:

```
public class vmAssignChallanToWholeSchool
{
    public int ChallanFormID { get; set; }
    public int SchoolID { get; set; }   
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AssignChallanToSchool()
    {
        vmAssignChallanToWholeSchool ChallanToSchool = new vmAssignChallanToWholeSchool();



    ViewBag.ChallanForm = new SelectList(db.ChallanForm.ToList(), "ChallanFormID", "ChallanFormNumber", ChallanToSchool.ChallanFormID);
    ViewBag.Schools = new SelectList(db.Schools, "ID", "Name", ChallanToSchool.SchoolID);

    return View();


}
```

View:

```
@model EBS_MVC.ViewModels.vmAssignChallanToWholeSchool
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AssignChallanToSchool";
}

<h2>AssignChallanToSchool</h2>


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChallanFormID, "ChallanID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList( "ChallanForm", new SelectList(ViewBag.ChallanForm))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChallanFormID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

and Do I need a custom ViewModel for this job, like the one mentioned ?

List of Hit and Try:

> EntityType: EntitySet 'vmAssignChallanToWholeSchools' is based on type
>   'vmAssignChallanToWholeSchool' that has no keys defined.
>   enter image description here
>
> System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the
>   name 'ChallanFormID'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correct then Challan is when someone participate in a school.

Therefore I think the whole setup would be easier if you do everything in the ChallanController. Then a simple Add would do what you want in the right controller.

Comment: To Save (CRUD) a Single Challan to a Single Student is working fine in the Joinning Table.
I want to Display a Different View to Select a School and a Challan, Thn to insert ID of Selected Challan and IDs of all Students of the Selected School  to be inserted in the above mentioned Joinning table.

Comment: Singe student can have more then One Challan and Single Challan can Have more then One Student (many to many)

Comment: Ok, my advice would then be to make a ChallanAndStudentsController. (Find a better word like participation or whatever). That gives you some advantages over using the other controllers. Else I don't really have any good advice.